# Correct approach for using related tables and possible workarounds?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am asking this question which is to teach myself of using correct approach in a certain scenario than any how-to-code problem.

Since I am self taught student and haven't used relational tables before. With search and experiment, I have come to know the basic concept of relations and their usage but I am not sure if I am still using the correct approach while using these tables.

I do not have any official teachers so only place I can ask troubling questions is here with you guys.

For example, I have written a little code where I have 2 tables.

1. Table-1 is `doctors` which has an `id` *(AI & Primary)* and `names` table of varChar.
2. Table-2 is `patient_recipts` which has a `doctor_name` table of tinyInt
3. `names` table hold the name of the doctor
4. `doctor_name` table holds the corresponding `id` from `doctors` table
5. `name` and `doctor_name` are related to each other in database

Now when I need to fetch data from `patient_recipts` and display doctor's name, I will need to INNER JOIN `doctor` table, compare the `doctor_name` value with `id` in doctor table and get the name of the doctor.

The query I will use to fetch patients of a certain doctor, is something like,

```
$getPatList = $db->prepare("SELECT *
        FROM patient_recipts
        INNER JOIN doctor ON patient_recipts.doctor_name = doctor.id
        WHERE dept = 'OPD' AND date_time = DATE(NOW())
        ORDER BY patient_recipts.id DESC");
```

Now if I were to INSERT an action log entry in some other processor file, it would be something like (action and log entry),

```
    $recipt_no = $_POST['recipt_no'];
    $doctor_name = $_POST['doctor_name']; //this hold id(int) not text
    $dept = $_POST['dept'];
    $patient_name = $_POST['patient_name'];
    $patient_tel = $_POST['patient_telephone'];
    $patient_addr = $_POST['patient_address'];
    $patient_age = $_POST['patient_age'];
    $patient_gender = $_POST['patient_gender'];
    $patient_fee = $_POST['patient_fee'];
    $logged_user = $_SESSION['user_name'];

    $insData = $db->prepare("
          INSERT INTO patient_recipts (date_time, recipt_no, doctor_name, dept, pat_gender, pat_name, pat_tel, pat_address, pat_age, pat_fee, booked_by) 
          VALUES (NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $insData->bindValue(1,$recipt_no);
    $insData->bindValue(2,$doctor_name);
    $insData->bindValue(3,$dept);
    $insData->bindValue(4,$patient_gender);
    $insData->bindValue(5,$patient_name);
    $insData->bindValue(6,$patient_tel);
    $insData->bindValue(7,$patient_addr);
    $insData->bindValue(8,$patient_age);
    $insData->bindValue(9,$patient_fee);
    $insData->bindValue(10,$logged_user);

    $insData->execute();

    // Add Log
    write_log("{$logged_user} booked OPD of patient {$patient_name} for {$doctor_name}");

OUTPUT: Ayesha booked OPD of patient Steve for 15
```

Now here the problem is apparent, I would need to execute the above mentioned fetch query **yet again** to get name of the doctor with ID comparison and bind the `ID 15` to Doctor's name before calling the `write_log()` function.

So this is where I think my approach has been wrong altogether.

1. One way could be using actual doctor name in `patient_recipts` rather than ID
2. but this would i, in first place, kill the purpose of learning related tables and keys, learning design scenarios and troubleshooting.

Please help so I can understand and implement a better approach for days to come :)

Comment: Your column names are confusing. Is `doctor_name` the name of the doctor or the ID of the doctor? Also, it seems like you sometimes say "table" when you mean "column", like "`doctor_name` table of tinyInt"

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about this confusing naming, the columns, yes, -not tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structure is correct, it's considered best practice to use the ID as the foreign key in other tables. If you want to include the doctor's name in the log message, you do have to do another `SELECT` query. A query like

```
SELECT name
FROM doctor
WHERE id = :doctor_id
```

is not very expensive.

But you can simply live with the log file only containing IDs. Look up the doctor's name later if you need to find out which doctor a particular log message is referring to.

BTW, when you use PDO, I recommend you use named placeholders (as in my example above) rather than `?`. It makes the code easier to read, and if you modify the query to add or remove columns you don't have to change all the placeholder numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Its a big relief for me now that I know I am on correct path :) Also, your mentioned query just didn't cross my mind. About named placeholders, I will now do as you suggested.